# Copy file to Windows Desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x, desktop, shutil

I want to copy files from a location to the current user's desktop path. To get this in Windows CMD it would be `%userprofile%\Desktop`

I tried:

```
source_path = r"\\cpd-sts\UsersSoftware\Cognos"
dest_path = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
file_name = "\\Impromptu_User.zip"
shutil.copyfile(source_path + file_name, dest_path + file_name)
```

And the output error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Users\\joshua\\Desktop\\Impromptu_User.zip'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
source_path = r"\\cpd-sts\UsersSoftware\Cognos"
dest_path = ("C:" + (os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")) + "/Cognos")
file_name = "\\Impromptu_User.zip"
shutil.copyfile(source_path + file_name, dest_path + file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix uses `/` for file separation, not `\`. Try the following:

```
source_path = r"/cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/Cognos"
dest_path = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
file_name = "/Impromptu_User.zip"
shutil.copyfile(source_path + file_name, dest_path + file_name)
```

Comment: The remaining backslashes are still erroneous. There is no need to escape a slash, but in an `r"..."` string every backslash is a literal backslash anyway.

Comment: Still not working...
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/cpd-sts/UsersSoftware/Cognos/Impromptu_User.zip'`

Comment: Are you on a windows machine or a mac?

Comment: I'm using Windows